# Detect first electronjs instance and show window if it exists

Tags: electron

Is it possible to show the 'first-instance' window on 'second-instance' event?

The case I am trying to achieve is to show the first instance's window whenever the user tries to open a second instance of the electron app.

Comment: Have you seen Electron's [`app.requestSingleInstanceLock([additionalData])`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelockadditionaldata) method. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I figured out that I was approaching the issue the wrong way, it's the primary/first instance that receives the 'second-instance' event, which is what I needed so the app can react if a second instance is started.